# Use De Moivre’s formula to show that $\cos^2 20^{o}+\cos^2 40^{o}+\cos^2 60^{o}+\cos^2 80^{o}=\frac{7}{4}$

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem.

Q: Use De Moivre’s formula to show that
$$
\cos^2 20^{o}+\cos^2 40^{o}+\cos^2 60^{o}+\cos^2 80^{o}=\frac{7}{4}
$$

I tried to let $z=\cos 20^0+i \sin 20^0$ and find $\cos 20^0=\frac{1}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right),\sin 20^0=\frac{-i}{2}\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)$,
$\cos 40^0=\frac{1}{2}\left(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}\right),\sin 40^0=\frac{-i}{2}\left(z^2-\frac{1}{z^2}\right),...$ But///
......

Comment: If $z=\cos20^\circ+i\sin20^\circ\implies z^n=\cos(20^\circ n)+i\sin(20^\circ n)$ for any integer $n$


$$4S=\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)^2+\left(z^2+\dfrac1{z^2}\right)^2+\left(z^4+\dfrac1{z^4}\right)^2=z^2+z^4+z^8+\dfrac{z^6+z^4+1}{z^8}+6$$

Comment: Rewrite as $\cos 40^{o} + \cos 80^{o} + \cos 160^{o}=0$.

Comment: Use `\circ` to denote the degree $\circ$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $z=\cos20^{\circ}+i\sin20^{\circ}$. Then,
$$
z^{2} = \cos40^{\circ}+i\sin40^{\circ}, \quad z^{3} = \cos60^{\circ}+i\sin60^{\circ}, \quad z^{4} = \cos80^{\circ}+i\sin80^{\circ}
$$
and
$$
z^{-1} = \cos20^{\circ}-i\sin20^{\circ}, \qquad z^{-2} = \cos40^{\circ}-i\sin40^{\circ}, \quad z^{-3} = \cos60^{\circ}-i\sin60^{\circ}, \quad z^{-4} = \cos80^{\circ}-i\sin80^{\circ}.
$$
Also note that $z^{9} = -1$, so $z^{-n} = -z^{9-n}$.

Setting $S=\cos^{2}20^{\circ} + \cos^{2}40^{\circ} + \cos^{2}60^{\circ} + \cos^{2}80^{\circ}$, we have
\begin{align*}
4S &= (z+z^{-1})^{2} + (z^{2}+z^{-2})^{2} + (z^{3}+z^{-3})^{2} + (z^{4}+z^{-4})^{2}\\
&= 1 + z^{2} + z^{4} + z^{6} + z^{8} + z^{-2} +z^{-4}+ z^{-6} + z^{-8} + 7\\
&= 1 + z^{2} + z^{4} + z^{6} + z^{8} - z^{7} - z^{5} - z^{3} - z + 7\\
&= 1 - z + z^{2} - z^{3} +z^{4} - z^{5} + z^{6} - z^{7} + z^{8} + 7\\
&= \frac{(-z)^{9}-1}{-z-1} + 7 = 7.
\end{align*}